# Using an ampersand (&) in a call to free()

Tags: c, pointers, free

Some code I'm looking at declares and later initializes a pointer to a struct.

```
mcsConsole_t *mcsConsole;
mcsConsole = (mcsConsole_t *) malloc(sizeof (mcsConsole_t) );
```

The typedef for this struct is:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int   reqType;             /* Request Type                */
    unsigned int   consoleID;           /* Console ID                  */
    int            returnCode;          /* Return code                 */
    int            reasonCode;          /* Reason code                 */
    unsigned int   ecbArea;             /* ECB posted for responses    */
    char           reserved[4];         /* Available                   */
    cmdRequest_t  *cmdRequest;          /* Pointer to command request  */
    cmdResponse_t *cmdResponse;         /* Pointer to command response */
} mcsConsole_t;
```

When this memory is freed, an ampersand is included in front of the pointer name.

```
free(&mcsConsole);
```

What is the purpose of this, and when do you use an ampersand with a call to free? I'm used to seeing code where memory is freed by simply supplying the pointer variable name.

```
int *ptr = malloc( sizeof(*ptr) );
free(ptr);
```

Comment: What is `mcsConsole_t` typedef-ed to? That might have something to do with it.

Comment: How is `mcsConsole` allocated? At a glance, this looks very strange and potentially buggy.

Comment: You need to read more of the code to get the context. How is `mcsConsole` initialized for example?

Comment: @PaulRoub Could there be a case it is not buggy? I can't think of any. Unless there is some self-implemented `malloc/free`

Comment: @tonysdg I added the typedef to the question.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Not that I can think of

Comment: So let's declare it is a bug/typo and close the question, I guess..

Comment: @Alex Still looks like a mistake, although we still haven't seen the initialization.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Could you theoretically do something like `&mcsConsole = malloc( sizeof(mcsConsole_t *) );`?

Comment: @tonysdg No... `&something` is rvalue.

Comment: Without more context it is hard to tell.  For all we know you're comparing tangentially related code that shares the same variable name.  I would suggest using a tool like cppcheck or clang's --analyze flag or gcc/clang's undefined behavior sanitizer.  Each of these tools could potentially point out a problem with this code.

Comment: I added the line where the memory is `malloc`ed. Unfortunately, the struct members are initialized in a PLX function that I cannot really understand.

Comment: @Alex It's a bug. And potentially a nasty one. What is the source of this code?

Comment: @EugeneSh. in the same time it is very likely to crash every time such `free` is called.

Comment: @ouah Well, UB is UB..

Comment: This reminds me of a piece of code I ran across awhile back that boiled down to: `T *t = new T(); T &rt = *t; delete &rt;`.  Granted this is C, not C++, so references aren't at issue ... however, what I learned from that experience was to look at how the code evolved into the state it's in using our source control tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in the program.

The object pointed at is `mcsConsole` which has either static storage duration if declared at file scope or automatic storage duration if declared at block scope. You can only free an object with *allocated* storage duration.

If you see `free(&p)` in a program and `p` is not a macro, it is probably a bug.

Answer (score 1):

That ampersand is getting the address of `mcsConsole`, which is itself a pointer to a `mcsConsole_t` structure. I can't think of a *single* scenario where that call to `free` would be valid. The system will attempt to `free` the *pointer*, which is on the stack (or possibly static), as though it were a structure allocated on the heap. This smells like a bug, and a particularly bad one at that.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered it is a bug in the code. The only case the ampersand notation can work with `free` is with array-like notation:

```
sometype_t *p = malloc(sizeof(sometype_t) * n);
```

then

```
free(p);
```

would be equivalent to

```
free(&p[0]);
```